# How to get Master parent node details from Rally API

Tags: c#, api, rally

I am trying to get master parent when I pass sub child ID like below

```
Request storiesRequest1 = new Request(leastchildId);
storiesRequest1.Query = new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Open");
storiesRequest1.ProjectScopeUp = true;
storiesRequest1.ProjectScopeDown = true;
storiesRequest1.Order = "Name";
storiesRequest1.Fetch = new List<string>()
{
    "Name",
    "ObjectID",
    "Parent",
    "Children",
    "State",
    "FundingPPMOpticsID"
 };
 QueryResult queryStoryResults1 = restApi.Query(storiesRequest1);

 rst = queryStoryResults1.jsonResult;
```

In above case, I am only getting parent node of passed ID, I want to get master Parent.

```
A - Need to Get this Parent ID  
  1-  
  2-  
    2a -  
    2b -  
        2.1a - Passing child ID
```

Please help me to get this.

Comment: What types are you working with?  Are they all epic stories?  Or PortfolioItems too?

Comment: its portfolio items..

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the best you can do is fetch Parent.  For stories there is a rollup field called Feature that will reference the lowest level Portfolio Item it is attached to, even if there are layers of epic stories in between.  But for Portfolio Items there is no such rollup field.  You'll have to manually traverse the hierarchy.

Depending what data you're trying to get at there may be a more efficient way to do your queries.  What exactly are you trying to do?